# How long does a Subscription ID stick around in Android?

Tags: android, sim-card, android-subscriptionmanager

Starting on API Level 22, there is native support in Android for Dual-SIM devices. At the center of the APIs, there is `SubscriptionInfo.getSubscriptionId()`.

Using these IDs, you can retrieve `SmsManager`s for each respective SIM card to send SMS and MMS. You can also identify through which SIM card an SMS was received on the `SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION`, and so on.

However, what is the lifetime of a Subscription ID? Can I store a Subscription ID in a local database and count on it to still be valid and pointing to the same SIM card later? By later, I mean after rebooting the device, removing its SIM card and popping it back in, or even after factory resetting the device.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tested the resilience of `SubscriptionId` myself, using two SIM cards, though on a Single-SIM device, since that is what I had available at the time.

First, I noted the `SubscriptionId` the system was giving me when SIM Card A was inserted. The `SubscriptionId` I was getting had a value of `2`.

Next, I restarted the device. The `SubscriptionId` after restart was still `2`.

Then, I turned off the device, removed SIM Card A and put in SIM Card B. After turning the device back on, the `SubscriptionId` changed to `4`.

Lastly, I turned the device back off, removed SIM Card B and put SIM Card A back in. After turning the device back on, the `SubscriptionId` changed back to `2`.

In conclusion, it looks like Android assigns a `SubscriptionId` unique to each SIM Card. The `SubscriptionId` seems to survive system reboots, and SIM Card removal and reinsertion. I did not test factory resets, but my gut feeling is that it probably will not survive those, since the system would not have any history of interaction with a SIM Card after a factory reset.

Comment: So you have tested this only on one device.

Comment: do we get SubscriptionId above android 10 ?

Answer (score 1):

From [the Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids#accounts)

> The Subscription ID provides an index value (starting at 1) for
> uniquely identifying installed SIMs (including physical and
> electronic) used on the device. Through this ID, your app can
> associate its functionality with various subscription information for
> a given SIM. This value is stable for a given SIM unless the device is
> factory reset. However, there may be cases where the same SIM has a
> different Subscription ID on different devices or different SIMs have
> the same ID on different devices.